# Sharepoint: Multiple Alternate Access Mapping Collections for Single Web Application

Tags: sharepoint

We have a SharePoint MOSS 2007 installation which has two different external hostnames.  When inspecting the setup I've noticed that there are two Alternate Access Mapping Collections mapped to the same web application.  Each AAM collection contains one url mapped to the default zone.

I can't see how AAM collections are mapped to web apps or even how to create a new AAM collection.  I've always thought that there was just a one to one mapping between web apps and AAM collections.

Does anyone have any idea as to how you would create such a situation?

Cheers
Russell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new AAM collections using the "map to external resource" link in the AAM page in Central Admin. You shouldn't be able to have one of these new collections point to an existing web application though, that throws errors when you try to do it.

Can you maybe post a screenshot of your AAM page (with the "show all" view) so we can see what you are talking about?

Also, the best source for learning about how AAM works is:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/06/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1.aspx

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot here...

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fb278ef58c.jpg

I've blacked out all lines exceot the two lines which both point to the same web app (but are in different AAM collections)

Comment: Yeah, my guess is this was done with the "map to external resource" link. The only one that is truly pointed at your web app is the one that points to the actual URL for your app. The other still works because DNS points it to the same IP.

Comment: Ah, yep, thats looks like whats happened.  Cheers for that! :-)

I don't suppose you know how to delete these mappings to external resources once they have been created?

Comment: Think I need to use stsadm -o deletezoneurl :-)

Comment: It is even easier than that - once you are in a collection, click the "Edit Public URLs" link, and there is a delete button.

Comment: Cool, Cheers Matt, much appreciated.  On our site though, I think this must have been left by some dodgy uninstall of a previous SharePoint site as the delete button was greyed out.  

Also, when I tried to run 

stsadm -o deletezoneurl -urlzone Default -resourcename http://www.abc123.com 

it failed with this message:-

The IncomingUrl is not present in the collection.

When I ran it as you would if you were deleting a regular AAM entry it removed it as normal:-

stsadm -o deletezoneurl -urlzone Default -url http://www.abc123.com 

This seems to confirm it was a dodgy entry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you create an AAM you are doing it for a web application. Since a site collection is inside of a web application those site collections will also work with the mappings. If you have multiple web applications you will want to make sure that you mapped the correct ones.

Comment: Hi there, cheers for the response but i think youre getting confused between site collections and Alternate Access Mapping Collections.  I have one site collection in my single web application.  The problem is I have two Alternate Access Mapping Collections associated with my single web application and I dont know how it got in to this state. :-S